# Checkbox centered to label

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

Can somebody help me to center the check box to his label? With the code below the check box is at the top.

```
<label for="checkbox">Label</label>
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it's just display perfectly inline. Can you give more code? maybe your css is make this issue

Comment: I guess it's not perfectly inline when using, for example, a bigger font.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the proper way but I handle this problem like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/AgKpQ/

```
label, input {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
label {
    font-size: 30px;
}
input {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

When using similar solutions you'll have to remember about the [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clearfix).

Answer (score 0):

Does input{[vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp):bottom;} what you want? If not maybe another of the valid values for vertical-align might.